# Powerpoint Interlocking mobius strip

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to recreate in Powerpoint Tina Seelig's framework on creativity for my course. The framework uses interlocking mobius strip as shown:[image: interlocking mobius strip]

I made a couple of parallel bands (6 basically), but I'm stumped on how to make them "weave" (go on top or below another band). When I use Bring to Front..it goes in front of all the bands. Appreciate very much inputs on how to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Hey there newbie py, as far as I know, you can't actually do that in PowerPoint, you need an image editing software for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the interweaved appearance you can divide some shapes to 2 parts:

[image]

Divided shapes can occur in different levels in the stack.

Powerpoint has very poor control for colorings. Your example has carefully adjusted gradient fills to make some 3D appearace. My old Powerpoint doesn't have arbitary gradient fill tools, but there's in the fill effects section vertical, horizontal and diagonal gradients to select from. Also the ending colors are selectable:

[image]

The shapes are not rectangular, they have fitting angles. Powerpoint has poor drawing tools, but you can cover parts with paper. A white shape without edge line can be used:

[image]

**Not asked:** It can be useful for developing tolerance and workaroundability to fight with Powerpoint's limitations, but still I recommend you to get a proper vector drawing program to make designs. Start with Inkscape (=freeware) if you cannot afford Illustrator,  CorelDraw etc.. And if you can afford them, it's still a good idea to try Inkscape. It has plenty of steam as long as you do not design for CMYK printing (=an area where Microsoft Powerpoint is as disabled)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to illustrate what can be done with Powerpoint and make suggestions on what's a more capable software for this context! Thanks!